# Custom CSV exporter - Cannot modify header information - headers

Tags: php, headers, export, csv

In my admin dashboard, i created a custom module for report filtering using custom queries. I need to add another functionality which is to export these results to CSV. I tried to create a very simple sample csv export.

```
ob_end_clean();
$output .= 'column 1'. ',';
$output .= 'column 2'. ',';

$output .="\n";
$output .='"data 1",';
$output .='"data 2",';
$output .="\n";

$file = "custom_table";
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");

echo $output;
```

Unfortunately, it produces an error.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output         started at C:\xampp\htdocs\rtlcbsasia\wp-admin\includes\template.php:1947) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rtlcbsasia\wp-content\plugins\wpdm-reports\wpdm-reports.php on line 38

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\rtlcbsasia\wp-admin\includes\template.php:1947) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rtlcbsasia\wp-content\plugins\wpdm-reports\wpdm-reports.php on line 39

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\rtlcbsasia\wp-admin\includes\template.php:1947) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rtlcbsasia\wp-content\plugins\wpdm-reports\wpdm-reports.php on line 40
column 1,column 2, "data 1","data 2",
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `header` after content has been sent to the browser, headers were already sent. Your code runs after part of the admin page it appears on has already been output to the browser. You can solve this by moving your output code into a function hooked to something that runs earlier, like [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init), or use the [`admin_post` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)).